# how can i run spesefic migration sector in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, migration

now im trying to migrate empty django project.

when enter this command

```
python manage.py showmagrations
```

result is

```
admin
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [ ] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [ ] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [ ] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [ ] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [ ] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [ ] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [ ] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [ ] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
contenttypes
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_remove_content_type_name
myapp
 [ ] 0001_initial
sessions
 [ ] 0001_initial
```

is this situation how can i migrate all of 0001_initial?

or how can i run spesific migrtaion step?

ex) admin 0001_initial only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's simple you have only put the app name and the migration you want to migrate

if you want to migrate the inital of the admin app:

```
$ python manage.py migrate admin 0001_initial
```

NOTE: it will unapply the later migrations